# Keep getting error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: node.js, express, openssl, cryptojs, xero-api

Going crazy trying to solve error on Node.js while trying to contact Xero API.

I've used a bunch of combinations of '.cer' and '.crt' and '.pem'.

I've followed the advice of a number of StackOverflow posters.

[Node.js https pem error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215083/node-js-https-pem-error-error0906d06cpem-routinespem-read-biono-start-line)

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Error (native)
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:327:26)
    at Xero.oa._createSignature (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/xero/index.js:19:68)
    at exports.OAuth._getSignature (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/xero/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:90:15)
    at exports.OAuth._prepareParameters (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/xero/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:300:16)
    at exports.OAuth._performSecureRequest (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/xero/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:309:31)
    at Xero.call (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/xero/index.js:51:20)
    at /Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/routes/external.js:47:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at expressInit (/Users/BeardedMac/projects/clause/clause-mean-stack/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:33:5)
```

Anyone out there have some insight?

The Xero API says it wants an X509 certificate...I'm not even making the call though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a PEM-encoded key as the `xero` module merely calls out to node's built-in `crypto` module to sign some data. Those types of keys start with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and end with

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

with base64-encoded data in between.

You can generate such a key using the `openssl` command-line utility:

```
openssl genrsa -out privateKey.pem 2048
```

Then read `privateKey.pem` in node like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/privateKey.pem');

// pass `privateKey` as the RSA private key to the `xero` module ...
```

Comment: I've used pem encoding, it does not seem to be working.  I created my certificates using the openssl command-line options

Comment: the api call from xero's node library asks you to enter an "RSA PRIVATE KEY"; I've used a number of filetypes of private keys, created by openssl, including crt, cer, and pem. Irrespective of which key I use, I get the same error.

Comment: You might show the actual openssl commands you're using to generate the private key.

Comment: this is the most recent:
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out csr.pem

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example `openssl` command line that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

Check your certificate format. Carriage return(\r) and new line(\n) should be there in the .cer or .crt format. Postman expects this.
This can be verified by opening it in notepad.