# NPM Install Fails - error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: node.js, npm, certificate, installation, pem

I am attempting to install the `expo` package from npm, but during the install process, I receive an error, `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`, multiple times as it tries to fetch .tar.gz files, and then the installation fails.

I looked around, but all I have been able to find is [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38215083/3103816) of that error when people were setting up their own servers and had issues with their certs.  But I'm not trying to set up a server, I'm trying to download a package, I don't have any certs to fix.  I looked at my id_rsa file in my ~/.ssh directory, and it appeared to be well formed with a start and end delimiter.

I thought this might be an issue with the package, but I had a colleague attempt to install the package and it worked for them.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I suspect it is an issue with my npm installation or configuration but I am at a loss as to what should be changed.

[npm debug log](https://gist.github.com/njenan/3b19e9ed43ca10cda6eb8e6233426c3f)

Here is the complete output:

```
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:testexpo kiddynamo$ node -v
v6.11.0
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:testexpo kiddynamo$ npm -v
3.10.10
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:testexpo kiddynamo$ npm install --save expo
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads/tarball/v4.1.0
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-svg/archive/5.2.0-exp.0.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/archive/v0.15.2.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads/tarball/v4.1.0
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-svg/archive/5.2.0-exp.0.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/archive/v0.15.2.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads/tarball/v4.1.0
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-svg/archive/5.2.0-exp.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/archive/v0.15.2.tar.gz
npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/kiddynamo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/kiddynamo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "expo"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/kiddynamo/git/barback/testexpo/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution to the issue.  Uninstalling Node via NVM and deleting my ~/.nvm, ~/.npm, ~/.node-gyp, and ~/.node_repl_history directories, then reinstalling Node fixed the issue.  Not 100% sure why but hopefully this is helpful to anyone experiencing the same issue.