# I can't install anything with npm command line

Tags: npm

I have been using `npm` for some time with ionic. Recently, it started giving an  error when trying to install anything both packages and modules. Even with react native it gives the same error.

I have tried re-installing it, but that didn't fix it. I created a new user on my Windows system, but it's still not working, and I noticed that when I search for the error code on Google, I get no results.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>`npm install -g ionic`
>   npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\OLAMIDE AWOBUSUYI\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-07-11T19_47_18_673Z-debug.log[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtxPY.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install Fails - error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM\_read\_bio:no start line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804976/npm-install-fails-error0906d06cpem-routinespem-read-biono-start-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the npm registry:

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```