# node-forge self signed certificate for https module

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, self-signed

OS: Windows 10
Node.js version: node-v8.11.4-win-x64
node-forge version: 0.7.7-dev

People,
i'm having a hard time trying to create an node.js https server.
The idea behind the server is that it's only for local loopback requests.
With it in mind and for the sake of privacy i thought of disposable self signed certificates renewed at each server restart.
Following suggestions i'm trying to use the node-forge module to generate the disposable certificates.

Reading their instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge i came with a very simple code:

```
var https = require('https');
var forge = require('node-forge');
    forge.options.usePureJavaScript = true; 

var pki = forge.pki;
var keys = pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(2048);
var cert = pki.createCertificate();

cert.publicKey = keys.publicKey;
cert.serialNumber = '01';
cert.validity.notBefore = new Date();
cert.validity.notAfter = new Date();
cert.validity.notAfter.setFullYear(cert.validity.notBefore.getFullYear()+1);

var attrs = [
     {name:'commonName',value:'example.org'}
    ,{name:'countryName',value:'US'}
    ,{shortName:'ST',value:'Virginia'}
    ,{name:'localityName',value:'Blacksburg'}
    ,{name:'organizationName',value:'Test'}
    ,{shortName:'OU',value:'Test'}
];
cert.setSubject(attrs);
cert.setIssuer(attrs);
cert.sign(keys.privateKey);

var pem_pkey = pki.publicKeyToPem(keys.publicKey);
var pem_cert = pki.certificateToPem(cert);

console.log(pem_pkey);
console.log(pem_cert);

https.createServer( { key:pem_pkey, cert:pem_cert },(req,res)=>
{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(443);
```

then it emits an error i make absolutely no idea what's about:

```
E:\forge_case\node-v8.11.4-win-x64>node.exe index.js
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAkTmxd1fWK+XL2Cp5+n82
mSe6iqM3qvwMEC+pIAlhpbangujOzKghnJaX4QsmBBBumNRN3zR2UOUAeYHmPS8v
3dbmgStB023aiFJ82ozewuGlykdQUFxWfR+OUA3xZcFZ7Ma+67tSJNtnkW4wNhzR
XImTCHYknu2dBAm7V2tGZKq/ZrKnY+f1VTW9t3jpw55ACjsFkMfqUenfDDAVFMwm
NnRpX1ecyVd2TEoeQ95k+q4Exm5AbxuqVMXVKHXMNZlq2ftG8tcrYS95Z3cAakVm
sxX8/BMZGZILG/30fdLPL8bZqGV+BXzz2AJ0egKLivunPtRpyI+Id0v1jYsrZ/9L
YwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

_tls_common.js:104
      c.context.setKey(options.key, options.passphrase);
                ^

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:104:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:805:25)
    at new Server (https.js:54:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\forge_case\node-v8.11.4-win-x64\index.js:33:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40986488/1094092

Comment: Found the problem, i was passing the public key to the https server instead of the private key.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pem_pkey = pki.privateKeyToPem(keys.privateKey);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.