# signature verification failed for JWT - node/express/identityServer/asp.net.

Tags: node.js, express, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I am having an issue with validating the JWT on the server side end of my node/express app. The token is being generated in Identity Server in an asp.net core app. The token that is generated is an RS256 token type, which means a private key and public key need to be generated on creation in the Identity Server. I need to retrieve a valid certificate with a valid signature.

On the client side (Angular) I'm passing in the Bearer token on all requests once signed in. I need to authenticate that token somehow. The way to do that with a RS256 token type is to make sure the public key matches. I'm using

> const jwt2 = require('jwt-simple');

For my JWT validation.

The issue is the secret, here is the jwt-simple documentation [jwt-simple link](https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple). If I make the third value in decode false it works, because it's ignoring the secret/cert that is required.

I'm making this validation in the middleware so all endpoints will hit it. 
I saw this issue - [SO Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584268/node-js-https-pem-error-routinespem-read-biono-start-line) and ran those same commands. I'm still getting the error because the token doesn't really have anything to do with the certs because I'm getting it from the Identity Server project. So I need to retrieve the cert public key from that project.

How would I be able to send that cert in the token or retrieve that valid cert somehow?

v1 - (using the self signed server.crt as the cert and getting this error)

> Error: Signature verification failed

App.js

```
//This is for a self-signed certificate locally with no correlation to the token itself.
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')
 };

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.headers.authorization){
        return res.status(403).json({ error: 'No credentials sent!'});
    } else {
        let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]

        var decoded = jwt.decode(token, options.cert);

        if(decoded){
            let currentTime = new Date().getTime()/1000
            if(decoded.exp <= currentTime){
                return res.status(403).json({
                    error: 'Token has expired'
                }); 
            }
        }
        else if(!decoded){
            return res.status(403).json({
                error: 'invalid token'
            }); 
        }
    }
    next();
})
```

JWT.io parsed token structure -

Header

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "1231231231231231231",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "x5t": "si7bdXd6......HnxhO4Wi_s"
}
```

Do I do anything with x5t? Apologies for the long post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the signing public key is provided with the token and you blindly trust it, it basically defeats the purpose of having signed tokens.

You need some other mechanism for sharing the authentication service's public key. Depending on your requirements for key rotations and how your app works in general, you can either get it from a static path/url when your app starts up, or you may want to build in a mechanism to periodically check for updated valid public key(s).