# Problem running an Angular 4 project and in using web-cam using IP address

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to run an Angular 4 project. It is a video chat app. When I am trying to run using `localhost`, it is not working and when I am using

```
ng s --host 192.16.10.xxx:4200
```

it's causing problems using the webcam and showing this error:

> [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDITS -**

I've generated ssl file `localhost.key` and `localhost.csr` and folder structure is

[image]

When I am trying to run

> ng serve --ssl --ssl-key localhost.key  --ssl-cert localhost.csr
>   --host 0.0.0.0

It is giving an error

```
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

Comment: Did you try without port as `ng s --host 192.16.10.xxx`

Comment: just as an additional pointer.  I think this behavior only happens in chrome.  if you want to temp. bypass you can use firefox

Comment: @jcuypers I tried firefox, but it is also giving an error.

Comment: @Rupesh strange. ok, well try the self-signed certificate. it will help for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to serve your project with an (self-signed) ssl certificate.   you can do this on the command-line or specify in in the configuration file.   you can find a procedure of generating a certificate and then for CLI.  the host part is optional

```
# angular generates a self-signed certificate for localhost automatically
ng serve --ssl 

-or-

# tries to use to the provided certificate, it it cannot find generate one
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key <ssl_key_file>  --ssl-cert <ssl_cert_file>
```

don't forget to import the certificate as a trusted root certificate into your pc/browser. you can check how to do this for each browser.

Comment: I've generated ssl key but On running the above command, it producing error `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
`

Comment: you need to replace the placeholders with actual values/filenames right?  mine for e.g. is  `ng serve --ssl --ssl-key c:\certificates\localhost.key  --ssl-cert c:\certificates\localhost.crt --host 0.0.0.0`  (i have copied the files in a specific directory after generation)

Comment: My files are `localhost.key` and `localhost.csr`. And these files are inside project parent folder.

Comment: yes so you need need to make sure you reference them correctly.  i'm using it here. i'm sure it works :)   if you are not sure, just create a specific directory and reference them like that, just to be clear it works

Comment: I've updated my query, please check that. I think I am giving the right path.

Comment: Sorry i can't simulate it on windows, but i have found this with similar error:  https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/63.  please check

Comment: I am using `ubuntu`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584268/node-js-https-pem-error-routinespem-read-biono-start-line

Comment: So I have to generate `.pem` and `.crt` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190993/discussion-between-jcuypers-and-rupesh).

Answer (score 0):

So, try to run your Angular app locally with certificate. You can generate certificate using open ssl

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -days 3560 -out localhost.crt -config certificate.cnf
```

and then run

```
"start": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-key d:\\certificates\\localhost.key  --ssl-cert d:\\certificates\localhost.crt"
```

I found this info on https://medium.com/@richardr39/using-angular-cli-to-serve-over-https-locally-70dab07417c8 site