# error:0906d06c:pem routines:pem_read_bio:no start line, when importing godaddy SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

I'm facing a problem with SSL integration with node.js when i integrating certificate and restart the server it shows `error:0906d06c:pem routines:pem_read_bio:no start line  Godaddy SSL certificate`

I'm using this code:

```
const https = require('https');   
const fs = require('fs');

var key=fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/../ssl/sslforfree_private.key','utf8');  
var cert= fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/sslforfree_certificate.crt','utf8');    
var credentials = {key: key, cert: cert};  
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = https.createServer(credentials,app);
```

Comment: I already did it on another project  by the same the difference is this project is deployed on aws ec2 linux environment and the success one is deployed on ubuntu server

Comment: I just fix it by saving private.key file as utf-8(without BOM).that works now