# How to set external proxy configuration for npm on windows

Tags: npm

I have external proxy IP Address `(222.22.22.222)` and with port 8888 and I'm trying to run npm I command from terminal it's saying error:

> 0909006c : PEM routines:get name:no start line.

I have set npm config proxy,http-proxy,https-proxy and registry with proxy ip and port with authentication.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyipadd:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxyipadd:port
npm config set http-proxy http://username:password@proxyipadd:port
```

Can any one please suggest me what I'm missing here?

Also I have to use system credentials right for authentication and also my password contains @ so I used percentage symbol and 40.

This is the error im getting on error log file

```
3401 verbose stack Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
3401 verbose stack     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:156:17)
3401 verbose stack     at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1130:48)
3401 verbose stack     at ondata (C:\nodejs\node-v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\index.js:154:20)
3401 verbose stack     at Socket.read (C:\nodejs\node-v10.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\index.js:89:12)
3401 verbose stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
3401 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
3401 verbose stack     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:554:12)
3401 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
3402 verbose cwd C:\Users\project
3403 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
3404 verbose argv "C:\\nodejs\\node-v10.16.3\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node-v10.16.3\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
3405 verbose node v10.16.3
3406 verbose npm  v6.9.0
3407 error error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
3408 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set proxy like this `npm config set https-proxy http://20.22.20.22:8080`
replace your IP address and Port

Comment: Yes I have added npm config set https-proxy 
   http://username:password@222.22.222.22:8080 and inplace of proxyip added ip address n port number

Comment: @santhosh can you please help me on this

Comment: There is no issue with command because command seems to be right but I think you are using some SSL certification on server . I dont know what exactly you are doing but as per the ```Error code 0909006c : PEM routines:get name:no start line.``` I found some url among that though below one is useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584268/node-js-https-pem-error-routinespem-read-biono-start-line

Comment: I'm trying to run npm install for installing all dependencies but when I run this npm install command I'm getting that error

Comment: @Santhosh i have updated my question with actual error im getting on error log file can you please look and help me. I think now you can know exact error im facing.

Comment: @venukumar As per my knowledge you can set proxy through  ```npm config set https-proxy``` and though code you can also set proxy. so you have use ```https-proxy-agent``` module. I am not sure why you both at same time.